# Capitalize first letter in string in c

Tags: c, string

I have a problem. This function that I have needs to clean a string of any non alphabetical characters, while lowercasing all of the alphabetic characters. Using pointers, `p_fast` checks to see if the character in the string is `isalpha`; if it is, the character is stored into `p_slow`. After doing this in the whole string, a `\0` character is added to complete the string. After this, I need to capitalize the first letter in the string that was just cleaned and lowercased.

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*                      Clean up customer names                       */
/**********************************************************************/
void clean_names(int quantity,
                               struct customer *p_customer_records_start)
{
struct customer *p_customer;
char *p_fast = p_customer_records_start->customer_name,
*p_slow = p_customer_records_start->customer_name;


for(p_customer = p_customer_records_start;
     (p_customer-p_customer_records_start) < quantity; p_customer++)
{
    p_fast = p_customer->customer_name;
    p_slow = p_customer->customer_name;

while (*p_fast != END_OF_STRING)
{
    if(isalpha(*p_fast))
        *p_slow++ = tolower(*p_fast);
    p_fast++;
}

*p_slow = END_OF_STRING;

}
return;
}
```

I don't know how to get back to the beginning of the string. I can't find anything on the internet. If anyone could help, that would be great! If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: The beginning of the string is still at `p_customer->customer_name`

Comment: @Kninnug I am aware of that, but `toupper(*p_customer->customer_name);` does not have an effect. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to do `*p_customer->customer_name = toupper(*p_customer->customer_name;` i.e. assign the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started with the pointer in `p_customer->customer_name`. In the end, that pointer still points in the same location (to the beginning of the name). You can use it to capitalize the first letter.

Comment: How would I do that. I have tried `toupper(*p_customer->customer_name);` already, and it does not do anything.

Comment: `toupper` doesn't do anything, it _returns_ something. You have to assign it somewhere, just like you do with `tolower()` in your loop.

Comment: @Barmar I see what you mean. I just took what you said and applied it. It works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: toupper only works on a single char per call. If you do something like this :

`p_customer->customer_name[0]=toupper(p_customer->customer_name[0]);`

It capitalizes only the first letter.